Question regarding modal logic version of disjunctive syllogism
Is the following theorem provable in SQML?
⊢ (A ∨ B) ∧ ~◊A → ☐B
Here's how far I got.

⊢ (A ∨ B) ∧ ~A → B [Prop.]
⊢ ☐(A ∨ B) ∧ ~A → B [1;NEC]
⊢ ☐[(A ∨ B) ∧ ~A] → ☐B [2;Dist.,MP]
☐(A ∨ B) ∧ ☐~A → ☐B [3; Modal logic]
☐(A ∨ B) ∧ ~◊A → ☐B [4;Df]
☐A ∨ ☐B → ☐(A ∨ B) [Mod. Log.]
☐A ∨ ☐B ∧ ~◊A → ☐(A ∨ B) ~◊A [6; Prop.]
☐A ∨ ☐B ∧ ~◊A → ☐B [7,5; Prop.]
☐A → A [M]
☐B → B [M]

I can see constructive dilemma can be used in 8,9,10 to get A ∨ B, but it's late and I can't see how to finish.

No, you can only derive B because A ∨ B only gives you something in the actual world. If you want ☐B then you need ☐(A ∨ B).
